# selecting a item from a list and edit

Tags: angular

A im trying to make a simple app that let the user click and select one of the items in the list wich then will appear on the input box thus letting the user edit the item. No problem compiling the code and the app renders well except that the selection part doesnt work

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'comb',
    template: `
  <div style="margin-left:1%;">
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li *ngFor="let CombtItem of CombtItems" (Click)="onItemClicked(CombtItem)"   class="list-group-item">{{CombtItem.nombre}}</li>
    </ul>
    <label for="Combt"> Item: </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Combt" [(ngModel)]="SelectedItem.nombre"  #CombtItem>
  </div>
    `
})
export class CombComponent {
  public CombtItems=[
    {nombre:"Test1"},
    {nombre:"Test2"},
    {nombre:"Test3"},
  ];

  public SelectedItem = {nombre:""};

  onItemClicked(CombtItem) {
    this.SelectedItem = CombtItem;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li *ngFor="let CombtItem of CombtItems" (Click)="onItemClicked(CombtItem)"   class="list-group-item">{{CombtItem.nombre}}</li>
```

Change `(Click)` to `(click)` <-- lowercase 'c'

Comment: i cant believe that was the problem, it got me changing and redoing the code haha anyways, Thanks